# Reading error while reading Json obect

Tags: python, json

I have a list of json objects like this:

```
json_data = [{"Timestamp":"4/1/2017 7:00","Maximum Demand (KVA)":123,"Consumption (KVAh)":271,"Power Factor":0.86},{"Timestamp":"4/1/2017 8:00","Maximum Demand (KVA)":119,"Consumption (KVAh)":260,"Power Factor":0.85},{"Timestamp":"4/1/2017 9:00","Maximum Demand (KVA)":125,"Consumption (KVAh)":264,"Power Factor":0.9}]
```

I tried json.loads but it is throwing an error:

```
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

tried this also:

```
with open(json_data) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
```

Error:

> TypeError: Expected String or Unicode

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: your json_data object is already python object, not json string, why do you want to parse it?

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to open a file from a json object?

Comment: your json_data must be a string if you want use json.loads

Comment: Just use `data = json_data`

Comment: Just add single ' around the json_data string if you really want to deserialize a string

Comment: Well, go first with the basics, json.loads is asking for a string and you're giving him a list, always check the type of your variables when TypeError occurs with `type(my_variable)`.

Answer (score 0):

jsons.loads transforms a stringified json to a python object. 
json.dumps transforms a python object to a string containing the corresponding json. Here you shoud use json.dumps.
data=json.dumps(json_data)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you...

```
import  json
json_data = [{"Timestamp":"4/1/2017 7:00","Maximum Demand (KVA)":123,"Consumption (KVAh)":271,"Power Factor":0.86},
             {"Timestamp":"4/1/2017 8:00","Maximum Demand (KVA)":119,"Consumption (KVAh)":260,"Power Factor":0.85},
             {"Timestamp":"4/1/2017 9:00","Maximum Demand (KVA)":125,"Consumption (KVAh)":264,"Power Factor":0.9}]


data = json.dumps(json_data)
print data
```

OUTPUT :

```
[{"Power Factor": 0.86, "Timestamp": "4/1/2017 7:00", "Consumption (KVAh)": 271, "Maximum Demand (KVA)": 123}, {"Power Factor": 0.85, "Timestamp": "4/1/2017 8:00", "Consumption (KVAh)": 260, "Maximum Demand (KVA)": 119}, {"Power Factor": 0.9, "Timestamp": "4/1/2017 9:00", "Consumption (KVAh)": 264, "Maximum Demand (KVA)": 125}]
```